# ubuntu cannot run any programs

Tags: python-2.7, terminal, ubuntu-14.04

I'd like to start by saying that I'm new to SO. Please let me know if I am not following the site's conventions.

I've just installed Ubuntu 14.04 (duel booting with Windows 8), and am trying to install CUDA, but noticed that trying to run programs via ./ yields errors. As a test, I wrote a quick python script:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    print 'hi'
```

and tried to run it from terminal. Calling it via python foo.py works fine, but ./foo.py from the same directory causes

```
line 3: syntax error: unexpected end of file.
```

This is the same error I get when trying to execute CUDA's .run file. Am I doing something extremely ignorant, or is it possible that some library is missing?

Comment: do you have the correct shebang line at the top of your program: `#!/usr/bin/env python`? Either way you should be running the script with the Python interpreter. `python myscript.py`.

Comment: Whoops! That fixed it. Doesn't really help me figure out what's going on with CUDA if my test is broken. Thanks @HunterMcMillen!